# Why is .then() fired before promise has actually resolved?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to return promises from async tasks so that I can use the **.then()** call to make them synchronous. Unfortunately, I'm experiencing some truly odd behavior. Basically, the third **then()** is executed before the second has resolved. Can someone explain what's going on? Here's my code:

```
function runReleaseLoop() {
  console.log('Starting release loop');
  const themes = ['blue', 'red'];
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    buildReleases(themes, resolve);
  })
}

function buildReleases(themes, onComplete) {
  console.log(themes);
  if (themes.length === 0) {
    onComplete();
  } else {
    const theme = themes.pop();
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(setTheme(theme))
      .then(someDelayedTask(theme))
      .then(buildReleases(themes, onComplete));
  }
}

function setTheme(theme) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(`Setting theme to ${theme}`);
    resolve();
  });
}

function someDelayedTask(theme) {
  console.log(`Starting delayed task related to ${theme}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Finished delayed task related to ${theme}`);
      resolve();
    }, 3000)
  });
}

// Run the process
runReleaseLoop()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Release loop finished')
  });
```

Here is my console output:

```
"Starting release loop"
["blue", "red"]
"Setting theme to red"
"Starting delayed task related to red"
["blue"]
"Setting theme to blue"
"Starting delayed task related to blue"
[]
"Release loop finished"
"Finished delayed task related to red"
"Finished delayed task related to blue"
```

Comment: So, for the functions that take arguments, I need to return a function that returns a promise?

Comment: yes correct (oops deleted first comment lol) but also you will need to act on the promise that returns, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling each of these function synchronously (`setTheme`, `someDelayedTask`, and `buildReleases`) and then passing their return values (promises) into `then` instead of passing the functions themselves into then:

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(setTheme(theme))
  .then(someDelayedTask(theme))
  .then(buildReleases(themes, onComplete));
```

Here is one solution:

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(_ => setTheme(theme))
  .then(_ => someDelayedTask(theme))
  .then(_ => buildReleases(themes, onComplete));
```

Here is the output of your code with the above change:

```
Starting release loop
[ 'blue', 'red' ]
Setting theme to red
Starting delayed task related to red
Finished delayed task related to red
[ 'blue' ]
Setting theme to blue
Starting delayed task related to blue
Finished delayed task related to blue
[]
Release loop finished
```

Comment: could you also do something like:
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(setTheme)
      .then(someDelayedTask)
      .then(buildReleases);

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that, you mix promises with callbacks. The second is you call all functions `setTheme, someDelayedTask, buildReleases` in one time:

```
function runReleaseLoop() {
  console.log('Starting release loop');
  const themes = ['blue', 'red'];
  return buildReleases(themes);
}

function buildReleases(themes) {
  console.log(themes);
  if (themes.length === 0) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  const theme = themes.pop();
  return setTheme(theme)
    .then(() => someDelayedTask(theme))
    .then(() => buildReleases(themes));
}

function setTheme(theme) {
  console.log(`Setting theme to ${theme}`);
}

function someDelayedTask(theme) {
  console.log(`Starting delayed task related to ${theme}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Finished delayed task related to ${theme}`);
      resolve();
    }, 3000)
  });
}

// Run the process
runReleaseLoop()
  .then(() => console.log('Release loop finished'));
```